# first and last words in alphabetical order in c

Tags: c, string

This is a c prog which takes 5 words separated by spaces and gives the first and last word acc to alphabetical order. eg.Enter 5 words: banana ap pa kiwi orange. first word=ap last word=pa.No error is shown but the prog isn't working, like more than 5 words are being accepted.This is my code:

```
void findWord(char word[][20], char *first, char *last);
int main()
{
    char word[5][20];
    char *first, *last;

    printf("Enter 5 words separated by spaces: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            scanf("%c", &word[i][j]);

    }
    first = word[0][0];
    last = word[0][0];

    findWord(word, &first, &last);
    printf("The first word is: %s and the last word is: %s  ", first, last);

}

void findWord(char word[][20], char *first, char *last)
{
    int k, l;

    for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    {
        for (l = 0; l < 20; l++)
        {
            while ((word[k][l] != '\0') && (word[k][l] == ' '))
            {
                if (word[k][l + 1]< *first)
                    *first = word[k][l + 1];
                else 
                    *last = word[k][l + 1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to learn how to debug since your program has multiple issues. Also, it is *much* better to break your problem up into smaller parts and then solve one at a time instead of writing the entire program in a single go and then wondering why it doesn't work. For starters, your input loop has issues because you are misusing `scanf`, among other things

Comment: Sorry, but questions of this sort really don't belong on Stackoverflow. What you've basically done is posted a code dump, said 'it's broke' and asked others to fix it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void findWord(char word[][20], char *first, char *last);
int main()
{
    char word[5][20];
    char first[20], last[20];
int i,j;    

    printf("Enter 5 words separated by spaces: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
       scanf("%s", word[i]);

    }
    strcpy(first,word[0]);
    strcpy(last,word[0]);

    findWord(word, first, last);
    printf("The first word is: %s and the last word is: %s  ", first, last);

}

void findWord(char word[][20], char *first, char *last)
{
    int k;

    for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    {
    if(strcmp(word[k], last)>0)
        strcpy(last,word[k]);
    else if(strcmp(word[k],first)<0)
        strcpy(first,word[k]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to compare the strings you can use `strcmp()` family functions and order the words alphabatically.
Instead of using the loop

```
for (l = 0; l < 20; l++)
        {
            while ((word[k][l] != '\0') && (word[k][l] == ' '))
            {
                if (word[k][l + 1]< *first)
                    *first = word[k][l + 1];
                else 
                    *last = word[k][l + 1];
            }
        }
```

use `strcmp()` to compare the words and sort them or to get the first and last vaule. `strcmp` can make the program easy and direct to solve.

Answer (score 0):

In while loop you should use '||' instead of '&&' here. try to debug your program step by step.